How can I disable highlighting of matching symbols in expression in version 14.1?
V 14.1 seems to have introduced another annoying eye candy feature. When the cursor is next to a symbol in an expression, all matching symbols become dark blue at same time.
I find this distracting. How can I disable it? This was not there in version 14.0. I am using Windows 10.
Here is an example of this behavior:
  DSolve[x''[t] + x'[t] + 3 x[t] == 0, x, t   ]


There is no such effect in version 14.0:


Set "SemanticSelectionHighlighting" in CodeAssistOptions to False with:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CodeAssistOptions -> 
  {"SemanticSelectionHighlighting" -> False}]

to disable this new feature, which

/.../ helps in reading code /.../ [and is] an enhanced version of something that’s actually common in IDEs.

If you want to completely disable all dynamic highlighting in the front end, use:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CodeAssistOptions -> {"DynamicHighlighting" -> False}]

